# Add new columns into a existing TABLE using the values from a select query as the name of the new columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to use the values of a existing column in a table as the name of columns created into another existing table. At the same time insert the values achieved from another table into the new created columns.
I have the following:
Table: "feature_description" containing 4 columns.
feature_id    feature_language    feature_name    feature_admin_name
    2                2            Laktosefrei:        Laktosefrei 
....
there are 8 values under feature-admin_name. I would like to add 8 new columns into a existing Table "products" named after these 8 values.
Until now I have the following Code.

```
<?php
if ($conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "xxxxxxx", "fk16"))
{   
$feature_index = "SELECT * 
                  FROM feature_set_values AS fsv  
             LEFT JOIN feature_value_description AS fvd ON fsv.feature_value_id = fvd.feature_value_id   
             LEFT JOIN feature_value AS fv ON fv.feature_value_id = fvd.feature_value_id    
             LEFT JOIN feature_description AS fd ON fd.feature_id = fv.feature_id    
             LEFT JOIN feature_set_to_products AS fstp ON fstp.feature_set_id = fsv.feature_set_id";
if ($filter_query = mysqli_query($conn, $feature_index))
{       
  while ($filter_name = mysqli_fetch_array($filter_query))
    {
        //$feature_name = array();
        $feature_name = $filter_name["feature_admin_name"];
        //$feature_value = array();
        $feature_value = $filter_name["feature_value_text"];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($filter_name['feature_admin_name']); $i++){
        echo $filter_name['feature_admin_name'][$i]."\n<br />";
        mysqli_query($conn, "ALTER TABLE products ADD (".$filter_name['feature_admin_name'][$i]." VARCHAR(50))");
        }           
    }
    //echo "</table>";
}   
mysqli_close($conn);
}
else {
echo "My Fehler";
}
?>
```

But all I get are just 4 columns added into table "products" named with the Initials of the 8 values!
The 8 values are: Laktosefrei, Glutenfrei, Gentechnikfrei, BIO, Herkunft, Milchsorte, Labart, Milchbehandlung.
But I get 4 columns with the names: L, G, H, M.
What am I doing wrong? Kann please somebody help me in this matter.
Thankyou.
when "var_dump" used,
    
 then I get the "echo" result:
[Result of "var_dump" by "echo"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uNNi.jpg)

Comment: `var_dump($filter_name["feature_admin_name"])` and add the output to the question please.

Comment: When I change the code: `$feature_name = var_dump($filter_name["feature_admin_name"] ` I get per "echo" the following: string(11) "Laktosefrei" string(10) "Glutenfrei" string(14) "Gentechnikfrei" string(8) "Herkunft" string(10) "Milchsorte" string(6) "Labart" string(15) "Milchbehandlung" . But no new columns are added to the table products.

Comment: First of all, you dont usually `var_dump` into a variable and then `echo` it. I am not sure if that is possible. You just `var_dump` the variable to see what is inside. About your issue, is the line `echo $filter_name['feature_admin_name'][$i]."\n<br />";` outputting the word fully or just the first letter of the word?

Comment: Thank you for your tips. the line `echo $filter_name['feature_admin_name'][$i] . "\n<br />";` give just the first letter of the word back.

Comment: And the line `mysqli_query($conn, "ALTER TABLE products ADD (" . $filter_name['feature_admin-name'][$i] . " VARCHAR(50))");` creates 5 new columns into table products. First of all these columns get just the first letter as their name. Besides it only creates each beginning letter of the names just once. That means for the values like "Laktosefrei" und "Labart" I become just one column with the name "L".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, special thanks to Kishor, who gave me the right tip with `var_dump()`.
I have now solved the problem as follows:

```
<?php
if ($conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "xxxxxx", "fk16"))
{
  $feature_name = array();
  $feature_index = "SELECT * 
                  FROM feature_set_values AS fsv  
             LEFT JOIN feature_value_description AS fvd ON fsv.feature_value_id = fvd.feature_value_id   
             LEFT JOIN feature_value AS fv ON fv.feature_value_id = fvd.feature_value_id    
             LEFT JOIN feature_description AS fd ON fd.feature_id = fv.feature_id    
             LEFT JOIN feature_set_to_products AS fstp ON fstp.feature_set_id = fsv.feature_set_id
               LEFT JOIN products AS p ON p.products_id = fstp.products_id";
if ($filter_query = mysqli_query($conn, $feature_index))
{
  while ($filter_name = mysqli_fetch_array($filter_query))
  {
    $feature_name = array('id' => $filter_name["feature_id"], 'name' => $filter_name['feature_admin_name']);
        foreach ($feature_name as $id => $name)
        {
          mysqli_query($conn, "ALTER TABLE products ADD (".$name." VARCHAR(20))");
        }
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Now, I get the 8 necessary values from the table `feature_description.feature_admin_name` 
as the name of 8 new columns added into the table `products` as needed.
Once again thankyou for your help and tips in this matter.